# Getting null values in table (Entity Framework)

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I been working on a database in entity framework but encountering some problems.

I have a HotelChain model like this:

```
[Key]
public int HotelChainID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Hotel> Hotels { get; set; }
```

and a Hotel model:

```
[Key]
public int HotelID { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }
public List<Amenities> Amenities { get; set; }
```

My HotelInitializer class:

```
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("Brussels", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("Paris", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("Berlin", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("London", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("Tenerife", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotel(new Hotel("Amsterdam", Repository.GetAllBuildings(), Repository.GetAllAmenities()));
        Repository.InsertHotelChain(new HotelChain("Company Name", Repository.GetAllHotels()));
```

The problem is that there are double records in my Hotel table in the database, one time with the HotelChain_HotelChainID on null and one time with the HotelChain_HotelChainD on 1. 
[image]

I'd like to achieve that only the records with the Hotelchain ID on 1 get added to the table. How could I achieve this?

These are my Repository methods:

```
    public static int InsertHotel(Hotel hotel)
    {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();
        context.Hotels.Add(hotel);
        context.SaveChanges();
        return hotel.HotelID;
    }
    public static List<Hotel> GetAllHotels()
    {
        HotelDbContext context = new HotelDbContext();
        return context.Hotels.ToList();
    }
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Seems like your Hotel class is missing a foreign key reference to HotelChain. In your initializer class you shouldn't be able to create hotels unless you have a hotel chain that exists. You should first add a foreign key reference first (as per your business logic - can a hotel exist in your system that's not part of a chain?). If you leave it out, you can still achieve what you're trying to do by first creating a hotel chain and then adding a list of hotels to that chain.

Comment: @RizJa For my business logic, a hotel should not be able to exist that is not part of a hotelchain, It is no longer listing null values now with this code: http://pastebin.com/Wc1W0nWV I also believe I will have to do tesame with the Buildings, Floors ... if I am correct? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Yes, the same logic would apply to Buildings and Floors.. a floor should only belong to a single building so you'd need a foreign key reference there as well. And not a problem.. you can either answer your own question and mark it as solved or I can put the comment above as an answer and you can accept that.

Comment: You can put the comment above and I will mark it as answered :)

Comment: Sounds good - posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your Hotel class is missing a foreign key reference to HotelChain. In your initializer class you shouldn't be able to create hotels unless you have a hotel chain that exists. You should first add a foreign key reference first (as per your business logic - can a hotel exist in your system that's not part of a chain?). If you leave it out, you can still achieve what you're trying to do by first creating a hotel chain and then adding a list of hotels to that chain.